# /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php - Laravel on Xampp Mac

Tags: laravel, xampp, bin

My Problem is . i have trouble to install the laravel framework on xampp.

Question: i try here to install xampp to mac os x. i get this back : after `which php` i get this /usr/bin/php but i need this.... /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php ? how or where is the problem.? 
let me know.

hallo 
someone 
can 
help 
me 
with 
the 
install

Last login: Mon Jan  5 03:49:16 on ttys000
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:~ spaceodyssey$ cd /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/L666
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:L666 spaceodyssey$ ls
CONTRIBUTING.md artisan     composer.json   public      server.php
app     bootstrap   phpunit.xml readme.md
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:L666 spaceodyssey$ which php
/usr/bin/php
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:L666 spaceodyssey$ 
Space-Odysseys-Mac-Pro:L666 spaceodyssey$

I'm happy to know how get this path after the which php >>> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php

Answer (score 0):

go to your terminal

```
open .bash_profiles
```

add this path to you path

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

and close the terminal

the open and write

```
which php
```

i think it will be as you like.

Comment: Hi! Stack Overflow has noticed that you're a new user and thus has put you up for review. I must say that this answer doesn't directly answer the question--if you do post an answer, it must directly answer the main question. While your instructions may work, any non-answer discussion should be in the form of a comment. Thanks!